# Changing parameter of javascript function

Tags: javascript, jquery, parameters, file-upload

I use the fileuploader for uploading photos, works like a charm.
But I would like to change the action-parameter when I click on a button (in this case, by clicking a specific journey).

I use this function to create my uploader:

```
function createUploader(){            
    var uploader = new qq.FileUploader({
      element: document.getElementById('file-uploader'),
      action: '<?=base_url()?>post/photo/'+$.cookie("journey-id")+'/'+$.cookie("journey-iso")+'/'
    });           
}

window.onload = createUploader;
```

I was working with the jQuery.cookie plugin. Through this session I thought to change the "action"-url of the createUploader() function. But since the createUploader() gets triggerd on window.onload, it doesn't work on change.

So my question is: is there a way to change this action-parameter when clicking a button? Something like this:

```
$("#menu a").live("click",function(){
  // change action-parameter now
  ...
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Gert

Comment: Have you had a look at the API documentation for this library?

Comment: Yes, but I do not see to find anything about it... https://github.com/valums/file-uploader

Comment: The readme claims there exists a `setParams(newParams)` instance method (after *Options of both classes*).

Comment: Fixed it. Not with the setParams() function, but by just recalling createUploader() again... it works, but I don't know if it's a good solution. I guess.